# Not Complete Statistic in Normal Distribution

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

> Given a sample $X_{1},...,X_{n} \sim N(\theta,\theta^{2})$ show, using the definition of completeness, that the statistic $T=(\sum_{i}X_{i},\sum_i X_{i}^{2})$ is not complete for $n \ge 2$.
>   Use the fact that $\mathbb{E}_{\theta}[2(\sum_{i}X_{i})^{2}-(n+1)\sum_i X_{i}^{2}]=0$

The definition of complete statistic given is:

> The statistic $T(\vec{X})$ is said to be complete for the distribution of $\vec{X}$ if, for every misurable function $g$, 
>   $\mathbb{E}_{\theta}[g(T)]=0 \; \forall \theta \implies P_{\theta}(g(T)=0)=1 \; \forall \theta$

So it is sufficient to show that $P_{\theta}(2(\sum_{i}X_{i})^{2}-(n+1)\sum_i X_{i}^{2}=0)\neq1$ but i can't figure out how.  Can anyone give me a clue?

Answer (score 2):

Let 
$
T_1 = \sum_i X_i$ and $T_2 = \sum_i X_i^2
$
and suppose $P(2T_1^2-(n+1)T_2=0) = 1$. Then $T_2 = \dfrac{2}{n+1}T_1^2$ a.s(P).
However by the triangle inequality,
$$
T_1^2 \leq T_2 = \dfrac{2}{n+1}T_1^2\quad   a.s(P),
$$
which is a contradiction for all $n>2$.