# Minimal sufficiency and completeness

Tags: statistical-inference, estimation, parameter-estimation

Let $X_1,X_2... X_n$ be i.i.d $N(\theta,\theta^2)$.Then why is $(X_{bar}, S^2)$ not complete despite the fact that $f(x,\theta)$ belongs to $k$-parameter exponential family and jointly minimal sufficient statistic for this family is also complete.

**P.S:** All variables have their usual meanings.

Comment: This is a curved exponential family which behaves differently from regular exponential family. As for completeness of the statistic, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2936487/prove-sum-i-1nx-i-sum-i-1nx-i2-is-not-a-complete-statisti/.

Comment: @stubbornatom thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove $(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i},\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}^{2})$ is not a complete statistic for $N(\mu,\mu^2)$ distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2936487/prove-sum-i-1nx-i-sum-i-1nx-i2-is-not-a-complete-statisti)